# Jquery not functioning on table created by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table which i created entirely by javascript and my Jquery code dont want to work with it :/ If i use it on Table which is created manualy (in html) i works just fine. See fiddle below.

FYI this jquery code should just alow user to use arrow keys for navigation between inputs (table cells)

Here is that [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zw9rbmsy/)

I load my scripts in head:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Table is created here (in body):

```
    <div id="myTable">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    createTable();
    addPerson(1);
    </script>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 13) {
            var thisClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
            $(this).parent().parent().next('tr').children('.' + thisClass).children().focus();
        }
    });

    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            $(this).parent().next('td').children('input').focus();
        }
    });

    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            var thisClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
            $(this).parent().parent().prev('tr').children('.' + thisClass).children().focus();
        }
    });

    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            $(this).parent().prev('td').children('input').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You connect event listeners only to existing elements. You should connect it to document to deal with dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
    // keycode first
    if (e.keyCode==40 || e.keyCode==13) {
    }

    // keycode second etc.
    if (e.keyCode==39) {
    }

    if (e.keyCode==38) {
    }

    if (e.keyCode==37) {
    }
});
```

UPD actually it is a bad idea to connect listener to a document if it is very large. You can attach listener to an element after creating it.

Comment: Why do you use so much listeners? Use only one.

Comment: thanks it works now. I use this much listeners because i am bad programer ;) thanks for that too, i will fix it when i learn how :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to bind the `keydown` event before the table was created. Try using the `on` method instead.

You also need to attach the event to an existing parent element that existed before the creation of the table, like in the body or another parent element.

```
$('body').on('keydown', "input", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==40 || e.keyCode==13) {
        var thisClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        $(this).parent().parent().next('tr').children('.'+thisClass).children().focus();
    }
});
```

Take this as an example. I would recommend you to use another wrapping element and bind via it's class or id, instead of element name.